# jquery toggle animations / in reverse order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I want something like this:
One button triggers the script and then when it's done, the same button would do the script in reverse (toggle)

*(Im learning javascript / jquery right now, so im a complete beginner)*

Example:

```
    <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){

                $("button").click(function(){
                    $("div").animate( 
                            {height: '250px'}, 
                            function(){ $("#hidden_txt").fadeIn(1000); } );
                });

            });
        </script>

<button>Start</button>

<div style="background:#98bf21; height:100px; width:100px; position:absolute;">
    <span id="hidden_txt" style="display: none">Hey, just checking !</span>
</div>
```

### **I found the solution with css class toggle, but:**

- When it's closing, the css classes need to be turned off in reverse order, so first fade out and then div going back to 100px height
- In IE9 and IE8 css transitions doesn't work :/

*( jquery 1.12.4 )*

Comment: you could look into **[GSAP](http://greensock.com/gsap)**. take a look at this **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tahirahmed/7uy4oy8q/)** for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following JS:

```
<script>

    var clicked=0;
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("button").click(function(){
            if(clicked==0){

            $("div").animate(
                {height: '250px'},
                function(){ $("#hidden_txt").fadeIn(1000, function(){
                    clicked=1;

                }); } );

            }else if(clicked==1){

                $("#hidden_txt").fadeOut(1000, function(){

                    $("div").animate(
                        {height: '100px'},
                        function()
                        {
                            clicked=0;
                        });

                });

            } 
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thx. So there aren't any better solutions for this ? For example if i had like 5 or more animations one after another ?

Also isn't it better to use bolean true/false instead of 0/1 ?

Comment: better with respect to what ? You can chain animations one after another- `$("div1").animate({height: '100px'}, function() {$("div2").animate({height:'200px',function(){  /*  Another animation here */}});});` ; You can either use boolen true/false or 0/1.

Comment: And then i need to chain them all in reverse ?

Comment: Well, for now its quite good solution for me (only 3 - 4 animations).
Thx for help! :)


Ps. Do you know any simple php tutorial for very basic but safe log in system and comment module ? I want to add something like cms just for one web site page. The content is like (title)(list), (title)(list) and so on, so it's a little bit like comments: (author)(comment).

Comment: It's about software, not tutorials or learning.
Well, never mind, i'm going to find something on my own :)